# How to use asterisk in a shell program

Tags: linux, shell, asterisk

I want to use Asterisk in a shell Linux program more or less like this :

```
asterisk -r && console dial 101
```

How can I do that ?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to run an asterisk command from your shell?

Comment: I am truly sorry, I'm not fluent in English.
It's exactly that, yes

Answer (score 2):

You can run an asterisk command by adding the `-x` option.

From the man page:

```
       -x command
              Connect to a running Asterisk process and execute a command on a
              command line, passing any output through  to  standard  out  and
              then  terminating  when the command execution completes. Implies
              -r when -R is not explicitly supplied.
```

So you can do something like:

```
asterisk -rx "pjsip show endpoints"
```